# What are the key bindings for scrolling through an intellisense list in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vsvim

What are the key bindings (hot keys) for scrolling through an intellisense list in VS 2015?

For example, in the following say I want to scroll down to "Ceil":

[image]

I've tried the arrow keys, pgup/pgdown, Alt-n/Alt-p, Tab, the arrow keys on Numpad with no success.  It would be nice to be able to scroll a line at a time, as well as a "page" at a time.

Note: I am using the [VsVim extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329), so maybe this is the problem? (although I have tried vi-ish keystrokes like "j", "k", "ctrl-j", "ctrl-k" to no effect)

My apologies if this is an obvious question, but I can't find any info about it anywhere, including under

`Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard`.

The mouse works of course, but since I'm a vi user I really don't want to take my hands off the keyboard.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After three days of receiving no answer, I assumed the answer was not obvious. So I decided to look further on my own.  While I was still unable to find any "official" key bindings, I was able to figure out what the problem was, and how to map the keys on my own.

First off, this is only a problem with the VsVim plugin installed.  With this plugin disabled, the arrow keys, and pgup/pgdown work *as expected*.  Also,  I noticed that even with VsVim enabled the pgup/pgdown **is** scrolling the list a page at a time.  I swear this wasn't working before, but at least now that appears to be working.

I also discovered a few properties of Intellisense that alleviate the need for scrolling.  First, intellisense is pretty good about presenting *contexutally* aware highlighting. For instance, on `Mathf` I select `PI` a lot.  So whenever I *dropdown* on MathF, it starts with 'PI'.  This somewhat alleviates the need to scroll around looking for something.  Second, I also discovered that if you're presented with a choice of `Atan` and `Atan2`, for instance, you can logically scroll to `Atan2` by typing `A2` and then tab completing (instead of having to type out 'Atan2').  So there are ways to *logically* select certain entries by typing contextual "hot keys" to logicially home in on your "target".

But still, there are lots of use cases where you simply want to scroll a line a time.  I noticed that the arrow keys didn't work **at all** in VsVim -- even when you're just scrolling around the text.  I decided I just needed to map the up/down arrows myself using Visual Studio.

To make a long story short, I mapped `Alt-j` to `Edit.LineDown` and `Alt-k` to `Edit.LineUp`.  You can either do this at the texteditor level, or the global level.  I just did it at the global level, since Alt-j and Alt-k are not in use by anything else, but if you're mapping a "popular" key binding you can restrict it to just `Text editor` mode as well.

Do this like so:

1. Goto `Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard`.
2. Search for key commands containing *down*.
3. Map `Edit.LineDown` to your specified key.
4. Do the same thing for `Edit.LineUp`.

Here is a screen print:
[image]

Now I can use the vi-friendly Alt-j and Alt-k to scroll through the list.  This is even better than the arrow keys because I can leave my fingers on the home row.  Yay!

Comment: It'd be nice to have this as the accepted answer :)